What is the motivation to consider only Z errors in magic state distillation
I have been learning about magic state distillation protocols and there is something I am not understanding correctly. So for the 15-to-1 distillation protocol that can be found in figure 3 in Magic State Distillation: Not as Costly as You Think, the authors describe how to distill a magic state using 4 faulty magic states and a $|+\rangle$ state. I understand that those states are encoded in surface code patches, and since the magic states are prepared injecting physical states to the patches then those are noisy. I understand how the protocol would be able to detect $Z$, e.g. the actual $T$ gates at the begining of the protocol result  to be $Z\cdot T$. Errors on such type can also happen in the multiqubit rotations, I also understand that.
My main doubt is why do we only consider such $Z$ errors when studying magic state distillation. In fact, in the answer of this question, it is said that only those errors matter or are considered. So why is that the case? i.e. do $X$ errors ($X\cdot T$) do not occur for some reason or are those harmless for some reason?

This is mainly because for $|T\rangle \propto |0\rangle+e^{i\pi/4}|1\rangle$, The effect of Pauli $X$ and $Y$ can be regarded as a coherent $Z$ errors.
$$
X|T\rangle \propto |1\rangle+e^{i\pi/4}|0\rangle \propto R_Z(-\pi/2)|T\rangle
$$
and
$$
Y|T\rangle \propto |1\rangle-e^{i\pi/4}|0\rangle \propto R_Z(\pi/2)|T\rangle
$$
As the MSD protocol for the $[[15, 1, 3]]$ code can be regarded as a QEC process, the coherent $Z$ errors should also be correctable as if the Pauli $Z$ errors. Therefore, we only need to consider $Z$-type noise for $|T\rangle$ states. Notice that this holds for any magic states that lie on $xy$ plane in the Bloch sphere.

Thank you! This clarifies my doubt, in fact I guess it's way simpler that I expected, don't knwo how I didn't think about it this way. Anyway, following up a little bit, I understand that the coherent Z error will then get discretized due to syndrome measurement, right? Also, I understand that that's why in the references I was mentioning they just consider the X stabilizers in the end, i.e. they omit the Z stabilizers, right?

So in the end it is like a classical code, the thing is that is should admit the transversal T, and if the transversal T results in a trivial operation, i.e. the sequence of Z rotations results in the identity, they puncture the classical code associated (after Gaussian elimination to map the sequence of gates), which just means to remove some of the T operations at the beginning right?

@JosuEtxezarretaMartinez For the 15-to-1 protocol, only the four $X$ stabilizer generators will be used to detect errors in the magic state. The other $Z$ stabilizer generators are there such that the whole code could admit transversal implementation of the $T$ gates and don't detect errors. I don't quite understand your second comments though.

@JosuEtxezarretaMartinez could you provide a link or proof to why the coherent Z error is the same as a Z error? Is this true for $R_Z(\theta)$ for arbitrary $\theta$?

@user1936752 so you can see the coherent rotation as a probabilistic thing between a case in which identity is applied and the Z is applied. When syndrome is measured, the classical measurement will tell if the state went to the identity or to the Z part of such coehrent error. This is called error discretization and comes from syndrome measurement. I'd say it is a corollary of the Knill-Lafflame theorem for error correction.

@Yunzhe Ok, thank you. Well so what I meant is that in the end the Z stabilisers are irrelevant for the protocol. Mostly based on the papers I referenced in the question. I mean, if the code is CSS, then both the Z stabilisers and X stabilisers should preserve the codespace under a transversal T. However, completely removing the Z stabilisers will not make the X ones to loose such property, implying that you can in fact remove those.
